# FireDAC Array DML and Returning clauses

Tags: firedac

Using `FireDAC`'s `Array DML` feature, it doesn't seem possible to utilise a `RETURNING` clause (in my case PostgeSQL).

If I run a simple insert query such as:

```
    With FDQuery Do
     begin        
      SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO temptab(email, name) '
       +'VALUES (''email1'', ''name1''), '
       +'(''email2'', ''name2'') '
       +'RETURNING id';
      Open;
     end;
```

The query returns two records containing the id for the newly inserted records.

For larger inserts I would prefer to use `Array DML`, but in some cases I also need to be able to get returned data.

The `Open` function does not have an `ATimes` parameter. Whilst you can call `Open` with `Array DML`, it results in the insertion and return of just the first record.

I cannot find any other properties, methods which would seem to facilitate this. I have posted on Praxis to see if anyone there has any ideas, but I have had no response. I have also posted this as a new feature request on Quality Central.

If anyone knows of a way of achieving this using `Array DML`, I would be grateful to hear, but my principal question is what is the most efficient route for retrieving the inserted data (principally IDs) from the DB if I persist with `Array DML`?

A couple of ideas occur to me, neither of which seem tremendously attractive:

1. Within `StartTransaction` and `Commit` and following the insertion retrieve the id of the last inserted record and then grab backwards the requisite number. This seems to be to be a bit risky, although as within a transaction, should probably be okay.
2. Add an integer field to the relevant table and populate each inserted record with a unique identifier and following insert retrieve the records with that identifier. Whilst this would ensure the return of the inserted records, it would be relatively inefficient unless I index the field being used to store the identifier.

Both the above would be dependent on records being inserted into the DB in the order they are supplied to the `Array DML`, but I assume/hope that is a given.

I would appreciate views on the best (ie most efficient and reliable) of the above options and any suggestions as to alternative even better options even if those entail abandoning `Array DML` where a `Returning` clause is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can get all returned ID's. You can tell Firedac to store the result values in paramters with {INTO }. See for example the following code:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT into tablename (fieldname) values (:p1) returning id {into :p2}';
FDQuery.Params.ArraySize := 2;
FDQuery.Params[0].AsStrings[0] := 'one';
FDQuery.Params[0].AsStrings[1] := 'two';

FDQuery.Params[1].ParamType := ptInputOutput;
FDQuery.Params[1].DataType  := ftLargeInt;

FDQuery.Execute(2,0);

ID1 := FDQuery.Params[1].AsLargeInts[0];
ID2 := FDQuery.Params[1].AsLargeInts[1];
```

This works when 1 row is returned per arraydml element. I think it will not work for >1 row, but I've not tested it. If it does, you would have to know which result corresponds with your arraydml element.

Note that Firedac throws an AV when 0 rows are returned for one or more elements in the arraydml. For example when you UPDATE a row that was deleted in the meantime. The AV has nothing to do with the array DML itself. When FDQuery.Execute; is called, you'll get an AV as well.

I've suggested another option earlier on the delphipraxis forum, but that is a suboptimal solution as that uses a temp table to store the ID's:
https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4693-firedac-array-dml-returning-values-from-inserted-records/